# Find a string in a dataframe and write row to a new dataframe (Pandas, Python 3.4)

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list of strings, called "participants", such as:

```
'3'
'5'
'6'
...
```

and a dataframe, called "numbers" :

```
Index   name  value
0       '0'    313
1       '1'    2343
2       '2'    15
3       '3'    62
4       '4'    97
5       '5'    157
6       '6'    144
    ...
```

I would like to create a new dataframe which contains all rows with only the names of "participants". The result should look like that:

```
 Index   name  value
0       '3'    62
1       '5'    157
2       '6'    144
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Extract the items with

```
newdf = df[df['name'].isin(participant_list)]
```

If you want the index to count from zero again,

```
reindexed_df = newdf.reset_index(drop=True)
```

Comment: Awesome! What if the strings in the "participant" list is not exactly the same as the names:

'3_a'
'5_b'
'6'
...

for example?

Comment: I'd extract the bits I needed on the fly with a list comprehension. eg. `[val[0] for val in mylist]` if you always need just the first value.

Comment: Updated to reset the index.

Answer (score 0):

I would do what rauparaha suggests. Another solution could be:

```
s = "name in %s" % (tuple(participants),)     
numbers.query(s)
```